# Cannot start up existing Meteor application

Tags: meteor

I have an existing Meteor app that appears to have crashed today. I re-ran meteor in terminal and it proceeds to run meteor but it’s not picking up correct db we are using in mongodb. When I run
`MONGO_URL=mongodb://dbuser:dbpass@127.0.0.1/db meteor run` it proceeds to build the application but then exits with a code:8. Then it just loops back to creating the application again and selecting package versions. Then when I visit our URL in the browser for the site, I’m getting the following error:

“It looks like you are trying to access MongoDB over HTTP on the native driver port.”

Not sure how to get this app back up and running so any help/suggestions would be appreciated. So short story is we had this running yesterday but then it crashed and now I can’t get the app running again. The db is intact and the collection we use is present in the db. The app code for meteor is all in place. I’m just having problems starting up the app again.  The app is hosted in AWS CentOS server running Apache.

Detailed error that I'm seeing when trying to run the app:

```html
/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:245
W20171114-03:34:08.618(0)? (STDERR)                                             throw(ex);
W20171114-03:34:08.618(0)? (STDERR)                                                   ^
W20171114-03:34:08.618(0)? (STDERR) TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'describe'
W20171114-03:34:08.618(0)? (STDERR)     at app/server/packages/npm-container/package.js:4:9
W20171114-03:34:08.619(0)? (STDERR)     at app/server/packages/npm-container/package.js:25:3
W20171114-03:34:08.619(0)? (STDERR)     at /var/www/mongo-parcc-user/parcc-meteor/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:222:10
W20171114-03:34:08.619(0)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20171114-03:34:08.619(0)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (/root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.115udz9++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
W20171114-03:34:08.619(0)? (STDERR)     at /var/www/mongo-parcc-user/parcc-meteor/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:117:5
=> Exited with code: 8
```

Comment: Have you tried running on a different port? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20788198/how-to-get-past-the-mongodb-port-error-to-launch-the-examples